# workbox cache get data for post request

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am using Workbox 3.6.1 now and I am really enjoy it.

But I just have a question about the post data caching of Workbox.

I may need to use the data which received from a request to post data to the server.

For example,

1. **Step 1:** the user enters his ID in the input field to validate his
   identity and then to help the website rendering the rest content (eg: another input field)
2. **Step 2:** And the user enter some other information and sends the data
       along with his ID to the server.

To my basic knowledge so far, I understand the Workbox can do the step 1 and 2 separately (I can only implement like this way......). But I just wondering if they will be queued together and when the website comes back online, the step 1 runs and the step 2 uses the data from step 1 and runs as well. During online, it can be done by using promises or callbacks. But i want to know if they are queued offline as well.

May be there is a way which I do not know, but I would like to know the official Workbox method to implement this case OR other workarounds.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I believe you're specifically talking about workbox-background-sync, and the short answer to your question is no, but you may want to chime in on this PR with your use case, as we're hoping to make it possible to do stuff like what you want in the next release: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/pull/1503